# Why is Lombok @Builder not compatible with this constructor?

Tags: java, lombok

I have this simple code:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class RegistrationInfo {

    private String mail;
    private String password;

    public RegistrationInfo(RegistrationInfo registrationInfo) {
        this.mail = registrationInfo.mail;
        this.password = registrationInfo.password;
    }
}
```

First I was using only the `@Builder` Lombok annotation and everything was fine. But I added the constructor and the code does not compile any more. The error is:

```
Error:(2, 1) java: constructor RegistrationInfo in class com.user.RegistrationInfo cannot be applied to given types;
  required: com.user.RegistrationInfo
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why is Lombok `@Builder` not compatible with this constructor?
2. How do I make the code compile taking into account that I need both the builder and the constructor?

Comment: From the error, i assume that 1) incorrect number of parameters in the constructor 2) incorrect parameters type is passed to the constructor

Comment: Does that happen for all constructors or for that particular one? Do you get an error even if you change parameters of constructor?

Comment: @wdc I have only one constructors (which is mentioned in the code). I need constructor with this parameter to be able to copy the object.

Comment: Did you check `@Builder(toBuilder = true)` ? This suppose to give you functionality of copy constructor. `Foo copy = original.toBuilder().build()`

Comment: @wdc just tried your solution. It's even better then with the constructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can either add an `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation, because

> `@Builder` generates an all-args constructor if there are no other
> constructors defined.

(Quoting @Andrew Tobilko)

Or set an attribute to `@Builder` : `@Builder(toBuilder = true)` This give you the functionality of a copy constructor.

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Foo {
    // fields, etc
}

Foo foo = getReferenceToFooInstance();
Foo copy = foo.toBuilder().build();
```

Comment: though it is a more concise way and [is backed up by the author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47093799/4922375), it is also counter-intuitive and involves the creation of an unnecessary instance (`foo.toBuilder()` here)

Answer (score 34):

When you provide your own constructor then Lombok doesn't create a constructor with all args that `@Builder` is using. So you should just add annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` to your class:

```
@Data //try to avoid as it's an anti-pattern
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationInfo {
    //...
}
```

Comment: What does the comment '//try to avoid as it's an anti-pattern' imply?
Do you mean that the use of @Data is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 14):

Presumably, `@Builder` generates an all-args constructor if there are no other constructors defined.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class RegistrationInfo {

    private String mail;
    private String password;

    private RegistrationInfo(RegistrationInfo registrationInfo) {
        this(registrationInfo.mail, registrationInfo.password);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I use the default constructor so I was forced to also add this annotation `@NoArgsConstructor`