# What is the class type of a @Builder object before calling build()?

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have done this before but forgot and couldn't find the answer easily online.

Let's say I have lombok on a POJO like

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
class Car {
    private int gallons;
    private int wheels;
    private String name;
}
```

and I want to use the builder notation in some logic

```java
public Car getCar(boolean isNew) {

    <I dont know what type to put here> carBase = Car.builder().wheels(4);

    if(!isNew) {
        return carBase.gallons(10).build();
    }
    else {
        return carBase.gallons(0).build();
    }
}
```

What type should I use to fill in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I was actually running into this error [Why is Lombok @Builder not compatible with this constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122400/why-is-lombok-builder-not-compatible-with-this-constructor) which was breaking my `@Builder` class.

Apparently lombok will generate a static nested class in the class annotated with `@Builder` called `<classname>Builder`, so to answer my original question there would be a valid class called `Car.CarBuilder`.