# In Scala, how to map a spark Dataset into a list of POJOs?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, lombok, apache-spark-dataset

I have a POJO defined in Java

```
@Data
@Builder
public class JavaItem {
    private String name;

}
```

I have the code in Scala

```
case class Record(name: String)

def asJavaItem(record: Record): JavaItem = {
    JavaItem.builder().build()
}

def recordDatasetToListJavaItem(record: Dataset[Record]): java.util.List[JavaItem] = {
    implicit val encoder: Encoder[JavaItem] = Encoders.bean(classOf[JavaItem])
    record.map(asJavaItem).collectAsList() // this fails
}

val recordDataset = Seq(Record("name")).toDS()

recordDatasetToListJavaItem(recordDataset)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 11: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 11: No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "JavaItem(java.lang.String)"
```

Why am I getting this error? I suspect this is a problem with encoders. How do I correctly map the `Dataset[Record]` to a list of `JavaItem` ?

Comment: I doubt Lombok and Spark will work nicely together without effort. Is there any reason not to collect as a list of `Record` and map it to `JavaItem` afterwards?

Comment: @GaëlJ I've been using Spark and Lombok for quite some time and didn't have any issues (as long as all required annotations are present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a no-args constructor on the Java pojo. Spark occasionally constructs the objects first and then later calls the setters for the single data fields. That's why you need a constructur `public JavaItem(){}`.

The following Lombok annotations work:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JavaItem {
    private String name;
}
```

The all-args constructor is required as - according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122663/2129801)- the builder only adds an all-args constructur if no other constructor is present..

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. In my actual Java POJO that I'm using, there is a nested structure. Every POJO in the structure needs the NoArgsConstructor and AllArgsConstructor. (Just an FYI for others that reads this solution)