# intellij how to generate constructor with same class object

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

With lombok we can use `AllArgumentConstructor` and some other comination.
Intellij also provies generator to construct with fields.

But i dont want to do something like this, specially lots of parameter

```
public User( User user) {
   this.id = user.getId
   ///////////////
}
```

Also i dont want to clone the object.
I have been looking for some annotation or a way to code least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build an object from an existing one using lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069561/build-an-object-from-an-existing-one-using-lombok)

Answer (score 1):

```
public User( User user) {
   this.id = user.getId
   ///////////////
}
```

Isn't this exactly the copy constructor?
Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor

Also see: [Build an object from an existing one using lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069561/build-an-object-from-an-existing-one-using-lombok)

Comment: i am really sorry. Actually i wa trying to avoid this way. I have updated the question.

Comment: Nothing more frustrating than invalidating answers by completely changing the thrust of a question